# C# declaring a 2D array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to setup a 2d array in C# to act as a maze to move a character around, I am having a few issues initialising the array, I am trying to do the below

but the InitialiseMaze method is saying the maze is not declared

Can anyone advise

thanks

simon

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace GameMan
{
    public class Maze
    {
       #region Variables
       static int[,] maze;

    #endregion
    #region Constructors/Destructors
    public Maze()
    {
        InitaliseMaze();
    }
    ~Maze()
    {
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    public void InitaliseMaze()
    {

         maze = {
                          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},    
                          {0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0},     
                          {0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0},     
                          {0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0},    
                          {0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0},    
                          {0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0},     
                          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},    
                          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},     
                          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},     
                          {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                          {0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0},
                          {0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0 ,0, 2, 0, 0},
                          {0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0},
                          {0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0},
                          {0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0},
                          {0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0},
                          {0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0},
                          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
                      };
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

Comment: I'm almost positive there should be a 'new' there during initialization. :)

Comment: why not put this in a file and load it from there?

Comment: Not related to question, but you'd have easier time designing maze if you'd put it in string like "   ####  " and use # for wall and space for empty spaces. Other characters could be other things one encounters in a maze. Then in initialization simply split the string into the int values and store as they're now.

Comment: @linkerro - If he can' even declare an array he certainly won't be able to read a file.  Besides an array will be faster.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't initialize an array like that other than in a variable declaration. However, the change is simple:

```
maze = new int[,] { 
   // As before
};
```

As asides:

- It looks like `maze` should be an *instance* variable rather than a static variable. After all, you're initializing it each time you create an instance of `Maze`
- You have a finalizer for no reason. Finalizers are *very* rarely required (or indeed advisable) in C#

Answer (score 2):

Ok, well here is some extract from the msdn :

```
 int[,] myArray = {{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}, {7,8}};
```

extracted from [MSDN multidimensional arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

you should also read up concerning Destructors, finalizers etc ... , I bet your coming from C++ ? Differences between the 2 languages arent always obvious :).

Comment: As Jon Skeet stated, finalizers are rarely required in C#. Never used them myself.

Answer (score 2):

Just to make Jon's post a bit clearer:

```
maze = new int[,]{
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},    
{0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0},     
{0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0},     
{0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0},    
{0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0},    
{0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0},     
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},    
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},     
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},     
{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0 ,0, 2, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
};
```

Boy, that was a big maze array...

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare maze

```
 numbers = new int[X,Y]; where X and Y are how big it is
```

Comment: Nope, that's inferred from the values. Just `new int[,] { ... }` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Two-Dimensional Arrays**

The simplest form of the multidimensional array is the 2-dimensional array. A 2-dimensional array is a list of one-dimensional arrays.

A 2-dimensional array can be thought of as a table, which has x number of rows and y number of columns. Following is a 2-dimensional array, which contains 3 rows and 4 columns −

[image]

Two Dimensional Arrays in C#

Thus, every element in the array a is identified by an element name of the form a[ i , j ], where a is the name of the array, and i and j are the subscripts that uniquely identify each element in array a.

**Initializing Two-Dimensional Arrays**

```
int [,] a = new int [3,4] {

   {0, 1, 2, 3} ,   /*  initializers for row indexed by 0 */

   {4, 5, 6, 7} ,   /*  initializers for row indexed by 1 */

   {8, 9, 10, 11}   /*  initializers for row indexed by 2 */

};
```

Explain above code:

```
new int [**3**,4] **3** denoting to rows like how may object in array 

eg:

{0, 1, 2, 3} ,  
{4, 5, 6, 7} ,  
{8, 9, 10, 11}


new int [3,**4**] **4** denoting to columns like total value in object (4 columns)

eg:   


   {0, 1, 2, 3}
```

Let us check the program to handle a two dimensional array

```
 using System;
    namespace ArrayApplication {
       class MyArray {
          static void Main(string[] args) {
             /* an array with 5 rows and 2 columns*/
             int[,] a = new int[5, 2] {{0,0}, {1,2}, {2,4}, {3,6}, {4,8} };
             int i, j;

             /* output each array element's value */
             for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

                for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                   Console.WriteLine("a[{0},{1}] = {2}", i, j, a[i,j]);
                }
             }
             Console.ReadKey();
          }
       }
    }

Output:  

a[0,0]: 0
a[0,1]: 0
a[1,0]: 1
a[1,1]: 2
a[2,0]: 2
a[2,1]: 4
a[3,0]: 3
a[3,1]: 6
a[4,0]: 4
a[4,1]: 8
```