# Matrix from math.net to array

Tags: c#, mathnet-numerics

I have a question for you.
I created a matrix in C# doing some mathematical operations using Math.Net. 
Now I would like to transform the matrix in a List or split its columns in more arrays.
My goal is to pass this matrix to a software which doesn't read matrices from Math.Net but only reads lists, arrays and so on from C# codes.

Thank you!

EDIT:
Here's my code:

```
Matrix<double>[] matrixC = new Matrix<double>[ins];
            for (int i = 0; i < ins; i++)
            {
                matrixC[i] = Matrix<double>.Build.DenseOfColumns(CjTR[i]);
            }
```

matrixC is a matrix of matrices created assembling some lists.
Here's my matrixC.

matrixC[0]

[image]

matrixC[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rv19G.png)

[image]

I'd like to know if it possible to split each column in arrays or list. Not Math.Net matrix anymore.

Comment: Provide a link to documentation for the Math.Net matrix class you have an instance of.  We can't guess which one you have.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Standard 2d matrix (or at least its data) is nothing more than a regular [2d array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays) or an [array of arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays).

Both those representation can be created with standard Math.Net methods on the Matrix class:

```
var matrix = MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Matrix<double>.Build.Random(3, 4);
var matrixAs2DArray = matrix.ToArray();
var matrixAsJaggedArrayPerColumn = matrix.ToColumnArrays();
var matrixAsJaggedArrayPerRow = matrix.ToRowArrays();
```

If you need to use lists/IList instead of arrays, then it can be done using [Conversion of System.Array to List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603170/conversion-of-system-array-to-list)

If you want to totally avoid Math.Net classes then you just have to [create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636344/c-sharp-declaring-a-2d-array) such [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342735/how-to-create-jagged-arrays-in-c) manually.

P.S.: In some cases it may make sense to use `IDictionary<(int row,int column), TValue>` as a way to represent a (especially sparse) matrix, but that is slightly different question.